# Is there a method in JQuery similar to "is_unique" in Codeigniter-4

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I want to ask if `is_unique` in CodeIgniter 4 is available in jQuery Validate?

I'm trying to solve my coding problem which involves the `is_unique` validation from CodeIgniter 4.

Here is sample of my code in `view.php`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('.formsave').length > 0) {
            $('.formsave').validate({
                rules: {
                    catcode: {
                        required: true,
                        is_unique: true --> this is the problem, although i'm just triying something here (testing)
                    },
                    catname: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    catstatus: {
                        required: true
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    catcode: {
                        required: "Please enter category code such as F & B",
                        is_unique: "Sorry, category code already taken, please choose another code for this category!"
                    },
                    catname: {
                        required: "Please enter category name such as Food & Beverage",
                    },
                    catstatus: {
                        required: "Please select Enable or Disable for the category You created",
                    },
                },
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

and here is my controller in `View.php`

```
public function validTest()
{
    $rules = [
             'catcode'   => 'required|is_unique[tbcat.cat_code]',
             'catname'   => 'required|is_unique[tbcat.cat_name]',
             etc.
    ];

    if(! $this->validate($rules) {
             // something here
    } else {
             //  another something here
    }
}
```

is there any method using `is_unique` within jQuery Validate?

Comment: There won't be OOTB because jquery is client-side and is_unique checks "against the database" (ie server-side).   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=is_unique

Comment: thank you @freedomn-m for your information. but is there really nothing else i can do about it? no other methods?

Comment: You would need to create a custom validation that makes an ajax request to your server-side that makes the check.  Here's an answer that does server-side validation, but it uses .net as the server-side, you just need your own custom server-side, the js would be similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280993/ajax-validation

Comment: There is the `remote` method you could try.  Also `if ($('.formsave').length > 0)` is completely pointless.  Using jQuery, when a targeted object does not exist it's simply ignored.  You may want to spend a little time looking at jQuery code examples.

Comment: I also question the entire idea behind this.  You want to use client-side validation to use ajax to check the database to validate something you are already checking via server-side validation.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky for the edit and information. from first info i do that the length > 0 its working but what i want is the is_unique in CI4. and the second, no i just want to server side checking. there is nothing in client side which can solve with html put the required tag.

Comment: @freedomn-m i've done that the remote thing. but the result of the console (i have to check it again tommorow) 302 or 303 see other.. `<?= site_url('categories/checkingData'); ?>` i've check it and all running normally.. sorry for late respond.. i've been on alert situation (take care of my wife pregnancy)

Comment: and many thank for closing this question.. since its not the same as i want and just close it, and there is so much different in the question with the one that suggested.

Comment: I know it's working, and I know it does not have to do with your original question, but I am trying to help you get better at jQuery...  `if ($('.formsave').length > 0)` is completely pointless.  Using jQuery, **when a targeted object does not exist, it's simply ignored**; you do not need to conditionally test its existence.

Comment: *"and there is so much different in the question with the one that suggested."* - Well, if you take the time to understand how it works, it's not so much different at all.  The `remote` method is the only thing built into this plugin that can talk to your PHP on the server via Ajax.  You can use it to see if the username is already taken... same as `is_unique`.  Why anyone would want to use this along with CodeIgniter validation is a mystery.